# SQL Linked Server returns error "no login-mapping exists" when non-admin account is used

Tags: sql, sql-server, security, linked-server

I have a local SQL Server 2008R2.  I have configured Linked Server to a remote database.

The Linked Server works great when I login to the local server using a SQL-login account with `sysadmin` server role.  I can query against the remote server, so I know the Linked Server setting is correct.  However, I would get the error below if I use an account that does not have the `sysadmin` server role.

```
Msg 7416, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
Access to the remote server is denied because no login-mapping exists.
```

For both local and remote servers, SQL login is used (Windows authentication is not used)

What kind of security I need to configure for a regular SQL-login account to use Linked Server?

Comment: If you right click . properties on the linked server definition and go to the Security tab, how is it set up? Alternatively script the linked server as Create and paste the `sp_addlinkedsrvlogin` part(s) (sanitising passwords etc.)

Comment: What @Nick.McDermaid said. If it says Not be made, you need to add a mapping to the list OR provide one of the 3 alternate options below  in the radio buttons.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, @BradD : I have added mapping to the list.  I have tried `Not be made` and `Be made using this security context`, and both options did not help.  However as soon as I added `sysadmin` server role to the local SQL account, it worked instantly.  Why?

Comment: I can't help unless you do as I asked originally - script out the `sp_addlinkedsrvlogin` parts. Otherwise I'm wasting my time trying to guess what your configuration is. I'm not aware of any kind of `sysadm` override.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As alternative solution you can use the parameter @datasrc instead of @provstr.
@dataSrc works without setting the User ID

Sample:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'LinkServerName', @provider=N'SQLNCLI',@srvproduct = 'MS SQL Server', @datasrc=N'serverName\InstanceName' 
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname = N'LinkServerName', @locallogin = NULL , @useself = N'False', @rmtuser = N'myUser', @rmtpassword = N'*****'
```

I've added a comment [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mdegre/2011/03/10/access-to-the-remote-server-is-denied-because-no-login-mapping-exists/), too, but it's not visible (don't know why).

Comment: I prefer your solution because the other doesn't address how to make it work if you have multiple User ID's

Answer (score 21):

**UPDATE**: See @Anton's and @Wouter's answer for alternative solution.

According to [this blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mdegre/archive/2011/03/10/access-to-the-remote-server-is-denied-because-no-login-mapping-exists.aspx), I have to specify `User ID` in the provider string if non-sysadmin accounts are used.  Here is an example.

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver 
    @server = N'MyLinkServerName',
    @provider = N'SQLNCLI',
    @srvproduct = 'SQLNCLI',
    @provstr = N'SERVER=MyServerName\MyInstanceName;User ID=myUser'
```

This exactly matches what I have encountered and it solves my problem.

Comment: Over a year later and you solved one of my head scratchers!

Comment: Note that the "User ID=" bit can be anything, i.e. "User ID=MickeyMouse", and it will work. Personally I prefer @Wouter's solution -- just leave out the "@provstr" parameter entirely, in favour of "@datasrc".

Comment: is it some bug !? for me that worked also but this is so strange

Answer (score 4):

After playing around with this, i found that you can avoid having to use the `User ID` property altogether, by using `@datasrc` instead of `@provstr`. This is very poorly documented, but the example below works for me:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver
    @server = 'SOME_NAME',
    @srvproduct='', -- needs to be explicitly empty, default is NULL and is not allowed
    @datasrc='some_server.com\SOME_INSTANCE',
    @provider='SQLNCLI';

-- Set up the Linked server to pass along login credentials
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin
    @rmtsrvname='SOME_NAME',
    @useself='true', -- Optional. This is the default
    @locallogin=NULL; -- Optional. This is the default
```

Using this method you can reuse the same Linked server for all of your users. The currently accepted answer has the huge drawback that you need to set up a separate linked server for each user.

Comment: Actually the "User ID=" bit can be anything, i.e. "User ID=MickeyMouse", and it will work. So you wouldn't need to have one Linked Server per user. Even so, I agree your approach is better -- just leave out the @provstr parameter entirely.

Answer (score 3):

You can also add remote server login mapping by right-clicking on your remote server -> Properties -> Security -> Add

[image: properties]

[image: login mappings]

Answer (score 0):

I tried @Wouter 's & @anton-r 's solutions and neither worked for me, but this did!

This is straight from Pinal Dave's solution (https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2019/06/07/sql-server-fix-msg-7416-access-to-the-remote-server-is-denied-because-no-login-mapping-exists/)

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'mylsname', @srvproduct=N'SQL', @provider=N'SQLNCLI11', @datasrc=N'123.45.6.789', @provstr=N'Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=yes;User ID=user_no_login'
```

GO

Interestingly, I do NOT have "user_no_login" on that server - I meant to change it to a user on that machine, but forgot.

Also of note: if you have the IP in the @provstr instead of in @datasrc then while it connects to  (local server, maybe?!), it doesn't connect to the server you're trying to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above worked, try this one liner:

```
ALTER SERVER ROLE [sysadmin] ADD MEMBER [userid]
```