# Access to the remote server is denied because no login-mapping exists. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7416)

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I'm trying to setup linked server on Access database (.mdb - without username and pass). Everything works fine for Admin account, however for anyone else it reports message: "**Access to the remote server is denied because no login-mapping exists. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7416)**". When searching this error, the proposed solution is to set "Be made without security context" for logins not added in remote login list.

But when I log in with other account credentials, this option is set to "Not be made", and above error is displayed. It's like there are different settings of linked server for different accounts.

With admin account
[image: With admin account]

With other account
[image: With other account]

Comment: did You managed to fix that? i have similar issue now

Comment: Yes. I can't remember exactly, I think the problem was that I was trying to create a view with one table from linked server. But I was establishing connection thru GIS software (MapInfo), and for some reason it didn't work.

Comment: check my answer bellow - it is ms bug ans simple not empty user is requred then it works fine ! ;/

Answer (score 0):

it is probably some bug
You need to add  to providerstring
`;User ID=asdasdasd'`

and realy
asdasdasd is good value here
it just canot be empty.
i belive some ms developer does not known how to replace null with new value for mapping ;/

source where i found.
[SQL Linked Server returns error "no login-mapping exists" when non-admin account is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32084453/sql-linked-server-returns-error-no-login-mapping-exists-when-non-admin-account)